# Collectionview controller as a containercontroller?

Tags: ios7, collectionview, container-view

Is it possible to create a collection view controller that acts as a `container viewcontroller`, meaning each cell is acting as a `container view` for a `viewcontroller`? Is there anything i should consider that scenario?